# Convert datetime format to date and time in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am looking to convert '2022-07-28T14:12:12.334Z' to a date column and the time to a time column in oracle sql?

Thanks

Comment: Oracle doesn't have a time datatype; both date and timestamp hold both date *and* time. Splitting the components into separate columns isn't necessary, both will still have nominal values for the elements you don't want, and it will make life harder when you want to use the data later. So then the question is which data type is appropriate - do you want to keep the milliseconds, or the time zone, or both? Will you get non-UTC (Z) values, and if so do you want to keep the original time zone or normalise to UTC? And which version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: I think I need the date only in format dd/mm/yyyy. The source is an extract from an online portal which is why the format comes out like this in excel and imported into a table.